# How to set lineHeight as multiple of default in Jetpack Composable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-layout

I have the following code. As you can see, the `lineHeight` on the Text composable is being set to a specific SP. I think it would be better however if I could multiply the default lineHeight by a float such as 1.2f so that I know I'm always making the lineHeight more than the default, and by what amount, rather than guessing.

Is this possible to do? I've tried to track down the default lineHeight in the source code but to no avail.

```
@Composable
fun ListItem(
    ritual: Ritual,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(modifier) {
        Text(
            text = ritual.name,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(
                    start = 16.dp,
                    end = 8.dp,
                    bottom = 20.dp
                ),
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            lineHeight = 24.sp
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the question that you want to set line-height using dp instead of sp?

Comment: @Abhimanyu no, the question is just "where can I find the default lineHeight for a Jetpack Text Composable?"